# docker login: error storing credentials `The stub received bad data.`

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, docker, aws-cli, amazon-ecr

First, I installed AWS-CLI and I already used "AWS configure" to set up my secret key and I also used "Docker login" command to log in and I got success and when I typed Get-ECRLoginCommand. It works and returns the result for me.

But when I try to use the command :

```
(Get-ECRLoginCommand).Password | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin 837859123533.dkr.ecr.ap-east-1.amazonaws.com/spring-boot
```

I got an error that looks like this:

> Error saving credentials: error storing credentials - err: exit status 1, out: `error storing credentials - err: exit status 1, out:`The stub received bad data.``

Comment: did you find a way to fix this? I'm having the same issue...

Comment: After a bit more research it seems the issue has something to do with the token size being larger than most credential managers can handle. See this discussion for details and possible workaround: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/4843#issuecomment-342712079

Comment: I have added a solution for the above issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74342675/9150731
Hope it would help!

Comment: no, different issue, this is the stub received bad data, your solution is for not implemented error.

Answer (score 47):

**Edit:** Also see Ethan Davis's solution:

> I found that removing C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin\docker-credential-desktop.exe and C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin\docker-credential-wincred.exe worked for me. – Ethan Davis Sep 29 '20 at 18:10

---

**Original:** The solution [linked by Joelster's comment](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/4843#issuecomment-342712079) worked for me.

> One quick workaround is to modify .docker\config.json file. **Remove the following line** so docker will use file system to store tokens:

> ```
>           "credsStore": "wincred"
> ```

I opened the file `c:\Users\sashoalm\.docker\config.json`, and I deleted the "credsStore" key. After that this worked:

```
type pass.txt | docker login -u AWS --password-stdin https://123123.dkr.ecr.us-west-1.amazonaws.com
```

And the output was this:

```
WARNING! Your password will be stored unencrypted in C:\Users\sashoalm\.docker\config.json.
Configure a credential helper to remove this warning. See
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#credentials-store

Login Succeeded
```

Comment: This did not work for me. Is there any alternative?

Comment: Not that I know of. If you find any solution, please come back and write it here so other people will know.

Comment: I found that removing `C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin\docker-credential-desktop.exe` and `C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin\docker-credential-wincred.exe` worked for me.

Comment: The above mentioned solution worked for me too. Thank you so much sashoalm.

Comment: Slick solution and time saving passing this blocking issue, now login credentials are stored in the docker config.json as it should be.
Thanks a lot for sharing

Comment: Worked for me (windows 10 + Docker desktop): renaming all 3 docker-credential-{desktop|ecr-login|wincred}.exe  _and_ making config.json a totally empty `{}`. I had done a Docker desktop restart and that had populated config.json with `{"credStore":"desktop","credsStore":"desktop"}` which I removed.

Comment: Thanks. By removing  "credsStore": "wincred" from C:\Users\norman\.docker\config.json worked for me!!!

Comment: Thanks for this sashoalm, you put me on to the right path. I was using Docker (WSL2 falvour) and WSL2 Ubuntu, so I ended up removing this config file from inside the WSL2 docker container which was ~/.docker/config.json (I actually wasn't that brave, and just renamed it .bak!)

Comment: In my case it simply worked to remove `"credsStore": "desktop.exe"` from my `~/.docker/config.json` file

Comment: Deleting docker-credential-desktop.exe, docker-credential-wincred.exe, and the config.json file made login succeed for me. I couldn't just delete 1 or 2, i had to delete all 3 of those apps/files.

Answer (score 19):

As of today's date, this issue still persists. Below are the things I discovered-

1.) This problem shows up while using SSOs for authentication. I am using Azure SSO for AWS.(https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-azure-login)

2.) The reason is- The token returned from SSOs is long enough(more than 2550 characters) where as windows credential manager does not support such long tokens.

3.) If you use ECR credential helper (https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-ecr-credential-helper), sadly it also does not seem to work with SSOs- https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-ecr-credential-helper/issues/229

However, I followed these steps as a workaround & I'm on Windows-

1.) Remove/Rename the `"docker-credential-wincred.exe"` file located in `"C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin"` directory.

2.) Remove the `"credStore"` & `"credsStore"` keys from the docker config(`C:\Users\PROFILE_NAME\.docker\config.json`).

I get the following response-

```
WARNING! Your password will be stored unencrypted in C:\Users\sandeep.kumar\.docker\config.json.
Configure a credential helper to remove this warning. See
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#credentials-store

Login Succeeded
```

- Tickets opened to address this issue-

https://github.com/danieljoos/wincred/issues/18

https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/5636

Comment: If you're running into this issue while using WSL2 don't forget that you have a separate .docker directory under your linux home directory!

Comment: Removing "credStore" key from C:\Users\PROFILE_NAME\.docker\config.json resolved my issue, thank you.

Answer (score 5):

As @Ethan Davis mentioned, **removing** the following files helped me:

- `C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin\docker-credential-desktop.exe`
- `C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin\docker-credential-wincred.exe`

Comment: But now I face this issue: Error saving credentials: error storing credentials - err: exit status 1, out: `error getting credentials - err: docker-credential-wincred.exe resolves to executable in current directory (.\docker-credential-wincred.exe), out: ```

Answer (score 4):

from another thread - [Docker Login failure on Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72709388/docker-login-failure-on-mac-os-x)
solution helps on Mac-os : `mv ~/.docker ~/.docker.bak`

Answer (score 4):

Fixed by just deleted    "credsStore": "desktop" in config.json file.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing worked for me, so I installed the Amazon ECR Docker Credential Helper, so you do not need to `docker login` at all.

```
choco install amazon-ecr-credential-helper
```

Place the docker-credential-ecr-login binary on your PATH and set the contents of your ~/.docker/config.json file to be:

```
{
    "credsStore": "ecr-login"
}
```

Official Repo: https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-ecr-credential-helper

Edit: In Windows you can download the `amazon-ecr-credential-helper` from here https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-ecr-credential-helper/releases and install it as described here:
https://pulseadvancedmedia.co.uk/aws/setting-up-aws-ecr-credential-helper-in-windows/

Comment: I am using this in git bash on windows.

Comment: You can install amazon-ecr-credential-helper as described here:
https://pulseadvancedmedia.co.uk/aws/setting-up-aws-ecr-credential-helper-in-windows/

Answer (score 2):

Both solutions worked for me, delete file C: \ Program Files \ Docker \ Docker \ resources \ bin \ docker-credential-desktop.exe and C: \ Program Files \ Docker \ Docker \ resources \ bin \ docker-credential-wincred. exe and delete {"credsStore": "...."} then my structure is as follows in the config.json file

```
{
  "auths": {
     "Account_AWS.dkr.ecr.Region_AWS.amazonaws.com": {
         "auth": "My token"
     }
  },
  "HttpHeaders": {
    "User-Agent": "Docker-Client / 19.03.13 (windows)"
  },
  "stackOrchestrator": "swarm"
}
```

Comment: Deleting the credential helper is a really bad idea - this will create problems further down the line.

Answer (score 2):

## **August 2023**

I've also face similar error and following all helps from this page. I'm using windows 10.

###### I've tried removing and/or changing the name of this file(s) from this dir `C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin`:

- `docker-credential-desktop.exe`
- `docker-credential-ecr-login.exe`
- `docker-credential-wincred.exe`

###### I've also tried to delete the `credStore` and `credStore` from `C:\Users\XXXX\.docker`

Deleting the 3 files above works but in my case everytime I open `Docker` it prompts that my wincred is missing and my Dockerhub is not connected.

My workaround is I'm just deleting the `config.json` file from `C:\Users\XXXX\.docker` without changing or deleting the 3 files above. That prevents the Dockerhub to disconnect and still be able to save AWS Configuration

Answer (score 1):

With the most recent version of Docker `amazon-ecr-credential-helper` is installed alongside it.

So you only need to activate it by modifying your `config.json` file, found in `%userprofile%/.docker/config.json` or `~/.docker/config.json`.

Set the contents of your `config.json` to be:

```
{
    "credsStore": "ecr-login"
}
```

Alternatively you can also set the contents to:

```
{
  "auths": {
    "XXXXXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.ap-east-1.amazonaws.com": {
      "auth": ""
    }
  }
}
```

(Where XXXXXXXXXXXX is the AWS Account number, ap-east-1 is the region of choice, and auth is left blank).

Now if you repeat the `docker login --username AWS XXXXXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.ap-east-1.amazonaws.com` then it will succeed this time.

The full instructions can be found on Amazon's [amazon-ecr-credential-helper](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-ecr-credential-helper#configuration) page.

Answer (score 0):

### September 2023

I faced the same issue described by @PangSoramDepo while running Docker Desktop 24.0.2 on Windows 10.

```
PS C:\Program Files\Git\usr\share\airbyte\airbyte-integrations\connectors\destination-<connector>> aws ecr-public get-login-password --region us-east-1 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin public.ecr.aws/asda23as
Error saving credentials: error storing credentials - err: exit status 1, out: `error storing credentials - err: exit status 1, out: `The stub received bad data.``
```

It was solved by backing up the files below:

- All files with the name pattern `docker-credential-{desktop | ecr-login | wincred}.exe` in the folder `C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin`
- `config.json` in the folder `C:\Users\XXXXXXX\.docker`

**No Docker restart was necessary in my case.**

Just a **WARNING** was emitted by **aws-cli/2.13.15**:

```
WARNING! Your password will be stored unencrypted in C:\Users\XXXXXXX\.docker\config.json.
Configure a credential helper to remove this warning. See
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#credentials-store

Login Succeeded
```

**Note that I'm authenticating to a public repository (ecr-public), which is likely subject to additional issues.**

Answer (score 0):

For those who may need it - in wsl the docker's config.json is stored separately in ~/.docker/ directory. I wasted some time modifying wrong files :o)

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10, 2024

I ran the *below* to change docker's config.json (`C:\Users\user\.docker`)

`echo '{"auths": {"https://index.docker.io/v1/": {}}, "HttpHeaders": { "User-Agent": "Docker-Client/19.03.12 (windows)"}}' > ~/.docker/config.json`

[Reference](https://github.com/docker/docker-credential-helpers/issues/190#issuecomment-898345425)