# AWS CDK: Error saving credentials: error storing credentials - err: exit status 1

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda, aws-cdk

Using AWS CDK, I am trying to deploy the Docker image with lambda function on AWS. And I am getting the following error.

```
[100%] fail: docker login --username AWS --password-stdin https://XXXXXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com exited with error code 1: Error saving credentials: error storing credentials - err: exit status 1, out: `Post "http://ipc/registry/credstore-updated": dial unix /Users/my_mac/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/backend.sock: connect: connection refused`

 ❌  MyService (prj-development) failed: Error: Failed to publish one or more assets. See the error messages above for more information.
    at publishAssets (/Users/my_mac/.npm/_npx/8365afa3375eae8d/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/util/asset-publishing.ts:44:11)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at CloudFormationDeployments.publishStackAssets (/Users/my_mac/.npm/_npx/8365afa3375eae8d/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/api/cloudformation-deployments.ts:464:7)
    at CloudFormationDeployments.deployStack (/Users/my_mac/.npm/_npx/8365afa3375eae8d/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/api/cloudformation-deployments.ts:339:7)
    at CdkToolkit.deploy (/Users/my_mac/.npm/_npx/8365afa3375eae8d/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/cdk-toolkit.ts:209:24)
    at initCommandLine (/Users/my_mac/.npm/_npx/8365afa3375eae8d/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/cli.ts:341:12)

Failed to publish one or more assets. See the error messages above for more information.
make: *** [deploy-local] Error 1
```

What can I do, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before deployment, open the Docker app/daemon on your machine.

Comment: This didn't work.  I tried running the Docker Desktop app & the docker image but the same error occurs.  I was able to fix it by following the tip [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69033886/1288913)

Comment: It did work for me, so I'd suggest to try and go from there.