# Docker push Error saving credentials: error storing credentials - err: exit status 1, out: `not implemented`

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-push

I have all AWS CLI and docker setup and running for a while. I changed the command codes to all run from a bash file. However, when running the `docker push` I get this error `` Error saving credentials: error storing credentials - err: exit status 1, out: `not implemented ``

I tried `AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE="aaa" docker push ...` and `docker push --profile=aaa` nut none of them either worked. I do not see any similar issue like 'not implemented' on Google!

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Try remedies mentioned in this issue - https://github.com/docker/cli/issues/1136

Comment: thank you @ErmiyaEskandary, I solved it by removing the credStore from the config file

Answer (score 11):

Here is the solution I found, thanks to [docker login: error storing credentials `The stub received bad data.`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60807697/docker-login-error-storing-credentials-the-stub-received-bad-data)

The .docker/config.json looks like this:

```
{
  "auths" : {

  },
  "stackOrchestrator" : "swarm",
  "HttpHeaders" : {
    "User-Agent" : "Docker-Client/19.03.8 (darwin)"
  },
  "credsStore" : "ecr-login"
}
```

by removing `"credsStore" : "ecr-login"` it worked!

Comment: This worked also on windows! Thanks!

Comment: This solution also worked for me:
Docker version 20.10.23, 
docker-credential-helper-ecr/0.6.0
The documentation stills says it's required. (https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-ecr-credential-helper#docker)

Answer (score 2):

if you are using docker on the mac

I was facing the same issue and it was resolved by

```
sudo chown -R $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.docker
```