# Docker Hub login failure on Mac

Tags: docker, macos, homebrew, dockerhub, colima

I am trying to log in to Docker Hub to be able to push my containers to my account. I am on a Mac using Homebrew. Docker and Colima are installed successfully and I am able to build and run containers just fine.

However, when I try to log in with `docker login`, after entering my username and password it sits for a second before returning this error message:

```
Error saving credentials: error storing credentials - err: exit status 1, out: `Post "http://ipc/registry/credstore-updated": dial unix /Users/<username>/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/backend.sock: connect: connection refused`
```

Comment: Try restarting docker

Comment: Thanks - I did try restarting colima but it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 19):

The problem here is probably that you have the .docker directory pointing things to Docker Desktop. Try `mv ~/.docker ~/.docker.bak` and restart colima and try it. I think you'll find that's what it is.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and this is how I fixed it:

1. Stop the Colima process
2. Swap out the old `~/.docker` directory:

   ```
   mv ~/.docker ~/.docker_bak
   ```
3. Restart Colima

`docker login` and `docker image pull` should work now.